# Internal linking issue on iPad gmail and yahoo

Tags: ipad, email, internal

I have been developing Email HTML Template using veeva iRep. but it has some internal links and these work well on desktop web clients. But internal links are having below issues:

1. Safari IPad - ymail : doesn't work at all
2. Safari iPad - gmail: works but when tapped, it remains in semi-hanged window I.e. user can't scroll up if internal link tapped.

Please help. Thank you in advance for your help